# How to talk about independency of two events from different experiments

Tags: probability

I'm new to probability. As far as I know now, according to the definition of independent events, there is a prerequisites that these two events $A$ and $B$ under considering must belong to the *same* experiment; or otherwise talking that $A$ and $B$ is independent or not is meaningless. (Am I correct here?)

Second, for example, let experiment $E_1=$ toss a fair coin with sample space $S_1$, $E_2=$ toss a fair dice with sample space $S_2$. Then I think that we can consider a new experiment $E$, refering to "first toss a coin and then toss a dice". Then the sample space is $S_1\times S_2$. And now we can talk about the independency about the two events $A$="toss a coin, the outcome is head" and $B=$"toss a dice, the outcome is point $3$". Is it correct that such way is *the only and standard* condition we can talk about such independency? I've checked Ross's book, but Ross didn't apparently give some explanation on this, even didn't give a terminology for such experiment $E$ (such as combined experiment), but isn't such technique important? And how can I find some explanation on this?

Comment: Can you think of a non-theoretical counter-example to your first statement?

Comment: @TonyHellmuth I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Especially if you are new to probability then you have a lot to deal with the construction of suitable sample spaces. If you persevere then once there comes a time that you have left that behind in some sort of faith that everything is settled in a suitable propability space that gives place to all relevant events. We actually have great freedom in modelling the reality in such a way that probability theory can be applied. By tossing a fair coin we do not necessarily even have a specific sample space in mind. So if another coin comes in then on forehand we think of it as modelled already.

Comment: That somehow explains what you experienced as a "lack" in the book of Ross. Yes, technique is important and you must know what's going on. Also you must know what constructions can be made. But again, once upon a time you will be able to rest in faith.